# fastboot flashall fails ('Unsupported reboot option reboot-fastboot') - AOSP 10.0.0 - blueline

Tags: android, android-source

I've just built android 10.0.0_r14 for a Pixel 3 (blueline) from a freshly downloaded AOSP repo under Ubuntu.

The init / sync / make sequence seems fine, but when I attempt to flash the resulting images, fastboot fails:

```
/home/XXXX/src/aosp$ /home/XXXX/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/fastboot flashall
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: b1c1-0.1-5578427
Baseband Version.....: g845-00017-190312-B-5369743
Serial Number........: XXXXXXXXX
--------------------------------------------
Checking 'product'                                 OKAY [  0.059s]
Setting current slot to 'a'                        OKAY [  0.376s]
Sending 'boot_a' (65536 KB)                        OKAY [  0.730s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   OKAY [  0.334s]
Sending 'dtbo_a' (8192 KB)                         OKAY [  0.180s]
Writing 'dtbo_a'                                   OKAY [  0.098s]
Sending 'vbmeta_a' (4 KB)                          OKAY [  0.120s]
Writing 'vbmeta_a'                                 OKAY [  0.069s]
Rebooting into fastboot                            FAILED (remote: 'Unsupported reboot option reboot-fastboot')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

This appears to occur for any version of 10.0.0, and whether I use fastboot from the Android SDK or the version I compile from AOSP.

Has anyone else seen this? If so, have you overcome it?

Comment: Does booting manually into bootloader work ( adb reboot bootloader or adb reboot fastboot )

Comment: Well, 'fastboot reboot' works fine, but the device no longer gets beyond the fastboot mode screen because there's no valid slot to boot (as a result [I think] of the problem reported).

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue when I was flashing the pixel 3.
Here is my solution:
First I flashed the Android 10 Factory Images Of Pixel 3 from Google. I used 10.0.0 (QQ1A.200105.003, Jan 2020, TMO/Fi). Then I tried to flash with my built aosp again. And this time it works perfectly.

Comment: Find factory images in this site: https://developers.google.com/android/images#crosshatch

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and got resolved by Flashing factory image. Once the device is up re-flash the built image. this works fine for me.